# Screen capture causing heap to grow

Tags: android, screenshot

I am trying to take screenshot using the code below:

```
final View rootView = getRootView();
rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(rootView.getDrawingCache());
rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Once captured, I am storing the screenshot in an `ArrayList<Bitmap>`.

```
mReporter.addBitmap(bmp);
```

The problem is, every time this whole process is performed heap grows by a large amount. How can I avoid the heap growing too large?

My log is showing this info which might be helpful:

```
05-08 20:11:48.443: I/dalvikvm-heap(18497): Grow heap (frag case) to 31.288MB for 6819856-byte allocation
```

Edit:

Am storing a max of 3 images in ArrayList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not. Everytime you store a new bitmap inside your `ArrayList`. You can either `downsampling` your `bitmap`s or you can keep only few bitmaps in your `ArrayList`

Comment: At anypoint of time am not keeping more than 3 bitmaps. I Will try downsampling :)

Comment: it's better. Remember that every bitmap will require widt x height x 4 bytes of memory. An 800x600 bitmap will require 2MB ca.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you not expect the heap to grow? You are storing a lot of information for each screen capture. If you want to avoid heap growth, you'll need to write the images to SD card or some other storage.